# Port forwarding - How to connect to remote postgresql server - No public IP

Tags: port-forwarding, putty, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin3

I would like to connect to postgresql server which is not a public IP.
 I need to do port forwarding to access the server. I used SSH client putty to do port forwarding.
 I keyed in 6666 under "source" field of Putty and 172.13.212.37:5432 under "destination" field of putty. Later, I launched pgadmin and keyed in 127.0.0.1 under hostname/ipaddress and 6666 under port, but still am not able to connect.
 Instead I get Fatal password authentication failed error. I am 100% sure that my password is right. Am I making any error in port forwarding?

**Scenarios tried**

[image]

1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcpDw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I making any error in port forwarding?

Probably, yes. The "destination" field in the tunnel declared in Putty must be the IP address and port of PostgreSQL **from the point of view of the server you ssh into**.

You mention it has no public IP, but `172.13.212.37` is a public IP address (see https://www.whois.com/whois/172.13.212.37).

In your case, it's a private IP address that is expected be in the "destination" field.
If PostgreSQL is running on the same server than the one you ssh into, that would be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`  , otherwise a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) address if the PostgreSQL server is reachable through the local network.

Comment: Yup.  From a linux ssh client point of view, the op wants `ssh -L3456:localhost:6543 user@remote` and his localhost:3456 will connect to what `remote` sees as localhost:6543.

Comment: @Daniel Verite - Apologies my postgresql ip is different from the above (172.13.212.37) and that's a private IP. I validated it using whois. So in destination, I have given the private IP address along with port number (5432). Then in pgadmin I configure 127.0.0.1 as hostname and my localport (6666) as port (This is the port number that I keyed in putty source field). But when I try to connect, I get the same error like password authentication failed.

Comment: @ivanivan - Did you get a chance to see my screenshots attached above? Only correction in the screenshot is, I will replace the Destination IP with my Private IP address where postgresql server is running and port number is same as 5432. I guess the pgadmin details in the screenshot are correct. Can you correct me if I am doing any blunder with the ports (am I doing it in reverser). I am not familiar with this networking concepts and am quite new.

Comment: Another issue which I would like to bring to your notice is that, when I use putty to connect to my postgresql server, I am able to connect to it successfully and execute the below psql command - "psql dbname selva". This lets me log into the db without any password prompt and am able to execute queries in command line

Comment: @Daniel Verite - You can find the two scenarios which I tried under "Scenarios tried" section in the question above but I still get the same error

Comment: With `psql dbname selva` it's using [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) to connect locally. The closest to that remotely with the ssh tunnel is to put `127.0.0.1` in the destination. Please try that. If it still results in "incorrect password", consider updating the password with psql's `\password` command.

Comment: @SELVA - I don't use `putty` so I have no idea on how to configure it with port forwarding.  I added the equivalent using the plain `ssh` client just so others could understand the answer a tad better.

Comment: @Daniel Verite - what you are saying is any different from 1st image under 'scenario tried' section shown above in the question? I have configured localhost in the destination.

Comment: @SELVA: right. Then you should have the same password error if you do `psql -h localhost  dbname selva` instead of `psql dbname selva`, on the target server, independently of setting up an ssh tunnel. Which would indicate it's a password problem, not an ssh tunnel/redirection problem.

Comment: @DanielVérité - Thank you Daniel. It worked. You are awesome

Comment: @DanielVérité - Can you please help me with the below post ?https://superuser.com/questions/1431377/password-prompt-not-displayed-putty-session-screen